# Can I force Mac OS X not to complain when a volume is removed without first unmounting it?

Tags: macos, mount

I have a USB flash drive that randomly disconnects itself from my Mac, and each time, I get a warning from Mac OS X (several computers, running 10.7-10.9) that it's been improperly removed.  I use it for portably storing Waves licenses, so I rarely write to it.  I'd like to suppress this message, as it's annoying and occasionally interferes with something I'm doing.  Can I get Mac OS X to shut up about this issue?  I tried using an NTFS filesystem on the drive to force it to mount read-only, but I still get a warning when it's disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind losing notification center, you can disable it.

To disable NC, thus stopping the removal message, type in:

```
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui KeepAlive -bool false
```

Then, type in

```
killall NotificationCenter
```

To re-enable it, type in:

```
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui KeepAlive -bool true
```

Keep in mind, besides disabling this message, it will disable **ALL** messages.